# Fight for your life!

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Try figure out what the answer is by looking at the image below. The answer is nine letters long.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> Colosseum

because

> V = Vertical
>  H = Horizontal
>  U = Up
>  D = Down
>  L = Left
>  R = Right
>  Now act out these moves clockwise with the only legal knight moves in chess on the board (starting from bottom left with the instruction "V"); You get "Colosseum" backwards:
>  [image]

Comment: That was fast, well done!